# Reading JAXA GSMaP data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, jaxa

I'm trying to process the daily rainfall data provided by [Jaxa](http://sharaku.eorc.jaxa.jp/GSMaP/)

The [documentation](http://sharaku.eorc.jaxa.jp/GSMaP/document/DataFormatDescription.pdf) says that the format of the dat file (say: gsmap_nrt.20170514.0.25d.daily.00Z-23Z.dat) is: `4-byte float plain binary,little-endian`

How can I read/process this data in QGIS or GDAL?

Comment: It looks like you could export the data to GoogleMaps (* .kmz).
KMZ you can read with QGIS.

Comment: @Mike The kmz contains 200x300 png tiles similar to the web interface. I doubt it can be easily used inside QGIS.

Comment: Maybe related: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_read_JAXA_GSMaP_data

Comment: @Kazuhito: Can you please post that as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks @DevdattaTengshe Don't you mind it is only for Windows OS?

Comment: No problems. If someone else has a Linux solution, they can post it as an additional answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JAXA provides a [format converter](https://www.gportal.jaxa.jp/gportal_file/tool/Common/FormatConversionTool_Setup%20v2.0.zip) which can convert HDF5/HDF4 and their binary products into either GeoTiff or KMZ. (NB: only for Windows OS).

Just in case the above direct link to the tool does not work, this is [JAXA Toolkit website](https://www.gportal.jaxa.jp/gp/tool.html) and the first one (highlighted) is the same link.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the tool depends on the MS Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 runtime DLL, which has been dropped from the Microsoft website. There are downloads available from other sites, but you may or may not trust them. I have taken them from https://www.wintotal.de/softwarearchiv/?id=6970

Comment: And I have to admit that JAXA does not guarantee future support.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the GDAL vrt driver to read the source data with a file named `test.vrt` like this:

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="1440" rasterYSize="480">
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="CFloat32" band="1" subClass="VRTRawRasterBand">
    <SourceFilename relativetoVRT="1">test.dat</SourceFilename>
    <ImageOffset>0</ImageOffset>
    <PixelOffset>4</PixelOffset>
    <LineOffset>5760</LineOffset>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

and these GDAL commands:

```
gdal_translate -ot Float32 -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 0 60 360 -60 -a_nodata -999.90002441406 test.vrt vrt1.tif
gdalwarp -t_srs WGS84 vrt1.tif vrt2.tif -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=10000 --config CENTER_LONG 0
```

This works on every OS for 24h accumulation files of 0.25 deg cell size. You need to adapt the `rasterXSize` and `rasterYSize` for other files according to the documentation, as well as re-calculate the `LineOffset` to `rasterXSize`* 4

The result can be loaded into QGIS, and looks the same as the tif created by the JAXA Format Conversion Tool (tested with data from 2017-05-01):

[image]

Comment: wow, proper QGIS/GDAL solution!

Comment: Feel free to wrap it into a QGIS plugin!